# Refreshing SYS.columns after db collation change

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

Let's say your database collation is set to `French_CI_AS` and that you have an `Employees` table with a `FirstName` column collation set to `database_default`.  If you run to following code to change the collation to `Latin1_General_CI_AI`, the `DATABASEPROPERTYEX` function will return `Latin1_General_CI_AI` while the `sys.columns` will still return `French_CI_AS`

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI;

SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation') AS DatabaseCollation
--Return Latin1_General_CI_AI

SELECT collation_name AS FieldCollation
FROM sys.columns
WHERE OBJECT_ID IN(SELECT object_id FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U' AND NAME = 'Employees')
AND NAME = 'FirstName';
--return French_CI_AS
```

If you run the same code a few second later, the `sys.columns` will eventually be updated.  However, is there a way to force an update of the `sys.columns`?

I already tried the `sp_refreshsqlmodule` and `sp_refreshview` StoredProc:

```
EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule N'dbo.Employees'
```

and

```
EXEC sp_refreshview N'dbo.Employees'
```

but they both raise an error (tried with the sa account and without dbo):

> Could not find object 'dbo.Employees' or you do not have permission.

Comment: Yes, I'm on the right database.  Single quotes are required since parameter for those StoredProc are NVARCHAR

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf Are you sure the collation on the column changes? From my testing altering database collation doesn't affect existing columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altering the database collation doesn't change the existing columns. You need to `ALTER TABLE`

```
ALTER TABLE Employees
  ALTER COLUMN FirstName VARCHAR(20) COLLATE  Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

Comment: You are right!  SSMS will display `<database default>` but it doesn't mean the column collation is linked to the database collation.  If you change the DB collation and reopen the column properties, `<database default>` will be replaced the real collation of the column.  The oposite is also true:  if you change the DB collation to match a column collation, SSMS will then display `<database default>`.